# What were the board dimensions of the Viking era bed finds?

Tags: vikings

While some boards were lost or too deteriorated to get exact dimensions, the reproduction of the Oseberg and Goteland beds had to be based on something.  The most I've been able to find were the overall dimensions of the beds and reproductions using modern lumber sizes.  What were the dimensions of the boards?  How big were the mortises?  Were all slats the same size?  From pictures I've been able to find, the slats closest to the head and foot of the Oseberg bed were wider than the middle slats.  Thank you.

Comment: Who made the reproductions?

Comment: The only credit I've found is Museum of Cultural History, University of Oslo, Norway.  The bed I am refering to can be found [here](http://irisharchaeology.ie/2012/09/the-oseberg-viking-ship-burial/).

Comment: If you haven't done so already, asking them directly could easily produce an answer.

Comment: Never heard back from them.